# How do you copy a contact from the SIM card to the phone in order to assign a picture to it

Tags: contacts, sim-card

Searching the site here has let me to believe that you **cannot assign a picture to a contact which resides on the SIM card** ( *I am using a Samsung Galaxy S, and that indeed seems to be the case - at least I haven't found a way to do it* ).

So I have to copy these numbers to my phone, I presume.

**How do I copy/duplicate one contact at a time from SIM to phone memory ?**

I especially ask 'one contact at a time' because I , some months ago, seem to remember having read that you can copy all contacts at once, but that is not the action I would like to take ( although, to be honest, I haven't even found that option, yet ).

Comment: There's lots of things you can't do with contacts on SIM cards, it's a very old, very limited storage format.

Comment: @GAThrawn: True , but that shouldn't prevent other software of extending it ( keeping a picture internally , linking it to the SIM card ). AFAIK, now, you have to duplicate all entries. If you than change the entry (phone number or such) on the phone, you don't have it on your SIM card any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I still hope that someone else gives me a easier and quicker solution, I have found the following procedure to be a fairly quick method to accomplish what I wanted ( someone else will certainly have another idea regarding this , I'm sure ) :

I send the contact information using the `Send via` Gmail to my own Gmail account, press `Download` in the received email and choose `Contacts` and `Phone`). Since all information is present in the .vcf file attached to the mail, I can now easily create/duplicate a new contact without having to enter the name and phone number again.

Answer (score 0):

This app looks like it claims to do so; whether it works is a different question.  You might want to buy it and try it quickly, and if it doesn't work then refund it before the 15 minute trial time is over.  https://market.android.com/details?id=com.happydroid.c2spro

Answer (score 0):

For the part of your question where you say you haven't yet found how to copy all contacts from SIM to memory: on my Galaxy S, if I go into **Contacts**, press <kbd>Menu</kbd>, select **Import/Export** I get the option **Import from SIM card**. It sounds like that's what you're after?

Comment: That copies all contacts though, does it not?

Comment: True, looks like I didn't quite read the question properly, sorry about that. Having gone back now and actually fully read it, i'll say that I was answering the "I haven't even found that option, yet" bit.

Comment: aha , I thought the import/export was an external dump (not between SIM and memory).