# What does the 'Mark as default' option do in my 'Edit' option of a contact

Tags: contacts

What does the **'Mark as default'** option do you can choose in the `menu` when you **select a contact** which is present in the **phone memory** ?

I am seeing this on a Samsung Galaxy S phone ( *if this should make a difference* ).

**-- background information (for those interested) --**

I am still trying to copy phone numbers one at a time from SIM to the phone memory ( [see my other question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7823/how-do-you-copy-a-contact-from-the-sim-card-to-the-phone-in-order-to-assign-a-pic) ).

At the moment the easiest way to accomplish this is to send the contact information using the `Send via` + Gmail to my own Gmail account, press `Download` in the received email and choose `Contacts` ).

Having done this for the few numbers I wanted to transfer ( *it's main reason being that I now can attach a picture and a ring tone to the important phone numbers, while still retaining these numbers on my SIM card should my phone suddenly die* ), I now noticed the '**Mark as default**' option in the menu of a phone number saved to the phone memory.

Before selecting this option, I wanted to ask what the option will actually accomplish.

Comment: +1. Good question... I don't see that option on the Droid Incredible. I would guess it sets one of that contact's multiple phone numbers as the default when you call that contact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm looking for documentation to back this up, but in my experimentation the "default" phone number for a contact is what's used with voice commands if you don't define a phone "type".

So, if I have three phone numbers for John Smith, if I just use the command `Call John Smith` the default phone number will be used. Otherwise, I need to use `Call John Smith home` or `Call John Smith mobile`.

It's also used if, when looking at a list of contacts, you tap the phone icon next to the contact's name. It will use the default phone number (if defined).

Comment: It is also used to dial/text from a home screen shortcut instead of popping up the list of all available phone numbers for the given contact.

Comment: The last point is what I usually run into. It's how you pick which name is displayed for the contact.